# TypeScript - Как передать метод класса родителя, дочернему классу?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Как передать метод класса родителя, дочернему классу?

```
class Parent {

    constructor() {
        this.children = new Children()
    }

    log(message) {
        console.log(message)
    }

}

class Children {

    constructor() {
        // Как здесь вызвать функцию log() из класса выше?
    }

}
```

Заранее, спасибо)

Comment: `this.log('текст лога')`, если бы Children действительно было дочерним классом :)

Comment: в текущем варианте кода: никак.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Parent {
  log(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}

class Children extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.log('sad'); //if there is no 'log' method inside Children class the result would do the same
    super.log('sad');
  }

  // log(mes) {  // try to uncomment this
  //   console.log(mes + 'children');
  // }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).